# How can I use exported functions with Express JS?

Tags: node.js

What I am trying to do is to call an exported function using **app.use()** from **Express JS** and I am not sure how to do it. I've tried the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = require('./routing');
var checks = require('./api/checks');
var app = express();

app.use(checks.tests());
app.use('/about', router);

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server started with port 3000.');
});
```

But once I try to start the Node server, I get the following error:

```
tests work correctly!
C:\xampp\htdocs\javsgreen_express\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\xampp\htdocs\javsgreen_express\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\javsgreen_express\app.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

And the JS checks.js is located in ./api/ correctly (./api/checks.js), and the code of that file is:

```
module.exports = {
    tests: function() {
        console.log("tests works correctly!");
    }
}
```

So, I am calling it wrong or I forgot something. **Oh, and now I have notices (I have tried once more before submitting this), the message "tests works correctly!, its displaying correctly in the console, just before the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a exported module as a middleware . I would suggest reading what [Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) is. You can not pass a regular function as  middleware. You are able to see the `console log` because `checks.tests()` is called and it returns a `console log`, but when `Express` tries to use it as a middleware. It breaks. Your syntax for using exported function is correct, It's just you are using it at wrong place.

P.S- If in future you are going to make your own custom middleware. Then this syntax might work

Comment: So, how should I call the function? Just using checks.tests() instead of app.use(checks.tests())?

Comment: To continue on Shivam's answer, as soon as you use checks.tests() you are immediately calling that function so you see the console log and then it hits the app.use that causes the error. If you use app.use(checks.tests) it'll delay execution until that code is triggered, i.e. until the API is used -- because it's being used as middleware. Without a route such as '/test' in app.use('/test', checks.tests) it'll use the function as middleware called regardless of endpoint.

Comment: @JavierGreen when do you want that function to be called?

Comment: @DillanWilding But if the reason of the code is just to check if a couple of folders exist, I can't call it this way, isn't it? With app.use() I mean, because the route exists within the checks.js code, so there is no point of assigning the same route twice, once in the app.use('./logs', checks.tests) and again in the tests script in checks.js ( fs.access('./logs', (error) => {}). I am sorry if I am not explaining myself correctly. And Sudhakar RS, I want to call this script once every time I start the server (node app.js in terminal).

Comment: @JavierGreen you need to call the function that (middleware) way only if you want to do something on every request coming

Comment: @SudhakarRS I think I understand it. So, if I need something in return, for example, routing, I need to use it that way (app.use()), otherwise, just calling the function normally (in this case checks.tests()), is the way to go, isn't it? Since I'm only checking if a x number of folders and files exist, and I don't expect anything in return. I am right?

Comment: @JavierGreen it's not just about getting something in return.Only if you want to do some operation for all the incoming requests, then you can create a middle & call using app.use()

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I understand it perfectly now!

Comment: @JavierGreen Using app.use() will use it either as an endpoint by supplying a route or middleware and run the code either every request to the endpoint or every request in general, respectively. If you want to run it once per service start then you can just call the function checks.tests().